# iOS 5: Geocoding on the basis of addresses from mysql database

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, geocoding

I am able to place a single annotation on MKMapView using the following code:

```
[self.geocoder geocodeAddressString:value completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                if ([placemarks count] > i) {
                    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                    location = placemark.location;
                    coordinate = location.coordinate;
                    coordinate.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
                    coordinate.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;


                    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
                    newRegion.center.latitude = coordinate.latitude;
                    newRegion.center.longitude = coordinate.longitude;
                    newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.029321;
                    newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.034589;
                    //newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.579321;
                    //newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 1.234589;
                    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
                    [annotation setCoordinate:coordinate];
                    //  AppDelegate *dataCenter = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                    NSArray *web = [detail valueForKeyPath:@"Name"];
                    NSString *value = [web objectAtIndex:0];
                    [annotation setTitle:value];


                }
            }];
```

Were value is the address that I pass.

But now, I want to use the same code (probably in a) for loop so, that I can geocode all the values of address obtained in an array from mysql database. Please guide me how to do
 so

UPDATE:

I get the values from my sql database in an array.

```
 $count = [web count];

    for (int i=0; i< count ; i++) {
            NSString *value = [web objectAtIndex:i];
            [self.geocoder geocodeAddressString:value completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                if ([placemarks count] > i) {
                    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                    location = placemark.location;
                    coordinate = location.coordinate;
                    coordinate.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
                    coordinate.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;


                    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
                    newRegion.center.latitude = coordinate.latitude;
                    newRegion.center.longitude = coordinate.longitude;
                    newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.029321;
                    newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.034589;
                    //newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.579321;
                    //newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 1.234589;
                    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
                    [annotation setCoordinate:coordinate];
                    //  AppDelegate *dataCenter = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                    NSArray *web = [detail valueForKeyPath:@"Name"];
                    NSString *value = [web objectAtIndex:0];
                    [annotation setTitle:value];


                }
            }];
}
```

COMPLETE METHOD::

```
-(void) showSourceDest {
if (!self.geocoder) {
    self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
}
AppDelegate *dataCenter = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"Opening: %@", dataCenter.data);
[self setTitle:@"Map"];

NSString *address = dataCenter.data;

[self.geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        location = placemark.location;
        coordinate = location.coordinate;
        coordinate.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
        coordinate.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;

        //for first co-ordinate :: SOURCE
        MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
        newRegion.center.latitude = coordinate.latitude;
        newRegion.center.longitude = coordinate.longitude;
        newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.029321;
        newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.034589;

        MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        [annotation setCoordinate:coordinate];
         AppDelegate *dataCenter = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [annotation setTitle:dataCenter.hotelname];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

        //second annotation for SDSU :: DESTINATION
       location2 = placemark.location;
        coordinate2 = location.coordinate;
        coordinate2.latitude = 32.774774;
        coordinate2.longitude = -117.072262;

        MKCoordinateRegion collRegion;
        collRegion.center.latitude = 32.774774;
        collRegion.center.longitude = -117.072262;
        collRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.029321;
        collRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.044589;
        MKPointAnnotation *annotation2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        [annotation2 setCoordinate:coordinate2];

        [annotation2 setTitle:@"SDSU"];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation2];

        NSArray *web = [detail valueForKeyPath:@"Address"];
        NSLog(@"NO OF VALUES:: %@", web);
        int count = [web count];

        //Other place of interest nearby
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            NSString *value = [web objectAtIndex:i];
            [self.geocoder geocodeAddressString:value completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
                    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                    location = placemark.location;
                    coordinate = location.coordinate;
                    coordinate.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
                    coordinate.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;


                    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
                    newRegion.center.latitude = coordinate.latitude;
                    newRegion.center.longitude = coordinate.longitude;
                    newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.029321;
                    newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.034589;
                    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
                    [annotation setCoordinate:coordinate];
                    [annotation setTitle:value];
                    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
                    [self.mapView setRegion:collRegion animated:YES];

                }
            }];
        }
    }
 }];
```

}

The block inside the for loop executes only once! :(
Not sure, but is it because the block variable is not getting updated?

Comment: Please see the update section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
newRegion.center.latitude = [[[detail valueForKey:@"Latitude"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
newRegion.center.longitude = [[[detail valueForKey:@"Longitude"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
```

where :

```
NSDictionary *detail;
```

So basically, [ doubleValue];

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues here:

- i is the index in your array of addresses for the database, it can't used to count throughout the placemarks that come back from geocoding one address. Just because you're on the 49th address it is unlikely that that address will generate 50 placemarks from the geocoded.
- Where does the `detail` variable come from and why do you get the same value out of it in every iteration of the loop?
- The `web` array is already in use as the target of the for loop, you can't expect to redeclare it within the loop.

if you  solve those issues you might be able to work out the rest of the code yourself. Also CLGeocoder limits you to 50 requests at a time. If you're doing that many you should consider storing the coordinates in the database along with the address strings.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Craig. I am new to Geocoding and so its kind of confusing to me. I will improve my code based on your inputs and will let you know how it goes. 
'detail' is NSDictionary that I get from json

Comment: I have updated the code. I am sure the CLGeocoder with not exceed the 50 limits count. So did not change that part of code. Only the first element in the array gets displayed while the remaining ones are not displayed

Comment: You new code shows the geocoder being used a to geocode inside its own callback block. Don' do that. Instead create a new one as the first line inside your For loop and give it new names for placemarks and error so you don't get confused about which ones you are using. Then check that `count` is actually > 1 and finally move the setRegion out of the loop, no need to call that for every geocoded address.

Comment: Thanks Craig for the inputs... I will change the code accordingly and will update you on how it goes. Thanks alot for being so helpful :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I still face a problem, block gets executed only once. I followed your instructions but I feel I am going wrong somewhere still and cannot figure out where?!

Comment: there are now three versions of your code in the question. Can you change it to show only your current version and then I'll look again. Also print out `count` to prove you have got the source data correctly.